# How to subtract time zone from a DATE column (BIGINT) in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table (MYTABLE) with BIGINT column (DT) where I store timestamps. I found out that these also contain local timezone of my users. 
I want to get rid of timezone from these values in my next database upgrade so that these timestamps would be UNIX epoch.

What SQL query should I consider (for GMT + 3 query example)?

```
UPDATE `MYTABLE` SET `DT` = `DT` - (3 * 3600000)
```

Is this OK?

I also need to run this UPDATE for date values that have milliseconds equal to zero. Should I convert `DT` to substring and look for last 3 characters to be zero? What is the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this sql statement:

```
UPDATE `MYTABLE` SET `DT` = `DT` - ? WHERE substr(CAST(`DT` AS TEXT), -3) = '000'
```

where `?` is an external variable calculated in Java that contains the time zone in milliseconds

Please someone confirm if this is OK

Answer (score 0):

If your data type is BIGINT, then, I will have to assume that you already store the date value as epoch time.  Assuming that you got that value from java.util.Date's `getTime()` method or from the `System.currentTimeInMillis()`, it seems that your database will not contain timezone information as `java.util.Date` and `System.currentTimeInMillis()` both are time zone independent.

Looks like it is more of display problem and you need to make sure that you display the date value in the right time zone.

[Look at version of `SimpleDateFormat` constructor that accepts `Locale` as parameter.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29)

Comment: If they are stored as epoch creating new Date objects with new Date(x) (x being the bigint from the db) and then using methods like .getHours() will return the hours adjusted for timezone of the device... At least I think it would...

Comment: Unfortunately your assumption of wrong and my data is stored with time zone.

Comment: I am curious to know how do you store values with timezone

Comment: Wand, I would be glad to write the whole backstory, but this is out of scope for this question.